Kotlin Apollo Client and GraphQL - rename auto-generated classes
we are using the Apollo client to generate our data classes in Kotlin. Our classes, e.g. Car and Person have a property MetaData that looks exactly the same for both classes. The client now generates two classes, MetaData for Car, and MetaData1 for Person.
Can I take influence on the naming or even force Car and Person to refer the same MetaData class?
Thanks in advance.
